# nth-child selector for a grid layout pattern

Tags: html, css, design-patterns, css-selectors, grid

I'm trying to solve a varying grid pattern using css nth-child (if possible without JS).

I'm trying to create this pattern to repeat down the page:

[image: repeating grid]

At the moment the best I can achieve is for the first 3 to be 33% width and then everything from there 25%

```
.service {
    width: 33%;
    &:nth-child(n+4),
    &:nth-child(n+5),
    &:nth-child(n+6),
    &:nth-child(n+7), {
        width: 25%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `:nth-child(7n+4)`, etc.

Comment: Awesome, :nth-child(7n+4),
           :nth-child(7n+5),
    :nth-child(7n+6),
    :nth-child(7n+7)
works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Target and repeat each one of the first seven items individually.

```css
article {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
section {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 50px;  
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: black
}
section:nth-child(7n + 1) { flex-basis: 30%; }
section:nth-child(7n + 2) { flex-basis: 30%; }
section:nth-child(7n + 3) { flex-basis: 30%; }
section:nth-child(7n + 4) { flex-basis: 20%; }
section:nth-child(7n + 5) { flex-basis: 20%; }
section:nth-child(7n + 6) { flex-basis: 20%; }
section:nth-child(7n + 7) { flex-basis: 20%; }
```

```html
<article>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>  
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>  
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>  
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>  
  <section></section>
  <section></section>  
  <section></section>   
</article>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fy5cbgnr/